# Error : Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, cmd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJoLA.png)

the flutter console is showing this error.
can someone please help how to resolve this issue

Comment: for a better understanding of your question please add the main error messages in the body of the question. I think you can copy paste from the command window.

Answer (score 1):

Open your android studio go to setting and select plugin from left side menu and search for flutter & dart plugins and install them, then restart your IDE.

[image]